# How do I select columns which has a dot in their column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select a record which clearly exists, but my SQL query does not bring it up. Any idea how to get this working?

> SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'local.email'='burgundy@email.com' LIMIT 1

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE \`local.email\`='burgundy@email.com' LIMIT 1`  Use backticks, not single quotes

Comment: @Siyual Post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you're using single quotes ( `'` ) around your column name, rather than using backticks ( ` ).

Try using this instead:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     Users 
WHERE    `local.email` = 'burgundy@email.com' 
LIMIT    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Crocodile said, anything that is a SQL variable like a table name or column name can also be surrounded by `` Back ticks (hold shift and hit ~). This tells SQL to look at them as literals.

Comment: _(hold shift and hit ~)_ might be true on a US keyboard, but my Swedish will do a caret ^ and I suspect many others will do other stuff.